# Is it possible to use a stream more than once?

Tags: java, inputstream

In short I need to do two things with one stream.

1. I need to pass a stream through a method to see if the bytes of that stream are of a particular type.
2. I need to create a new class using that stream once that check is completed.

I'm very new to streams and I know that they are "one way streets."  So I think I have a bad design in my code or something if I find myself needing to reuse a stream.

Here is a snippit of the logic:

```
byte[] header = new byte[1024];
//reads entire array or until EOF whichever is first
bis.mark(header.length);
bis.read(header);

if(isFileType(header)) {
   bis.reset();
  _data.put(fileName, new MyClass(bis)); // Stream is now closed...
  methodForFinalBytes(bis);
} else {
  // Do other stuff;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends entirely on whether the `InputStream` implementation supports `mark()`. See http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/InputStream.html#markSupported(). Calling `reset()` on a stream that doesn't support `mark()` may throw an exception.

`BufferedInputStream` and `ByteArrayInputStream` support `mark()`, but others don't.

Answer (score 1):

Generally, you can't reset an InputStream to get back to the start. There are, however the mark() / reset() methods, which make a stream remember the current position and you can rewind the stream to the marked position with reset().

Problem is, they are optional and may not be supported by the particular stream class in use. BufferedInputStream does support mark() / reset() (although within buffer limits). You can wrap your InputStream in a BufferedInputStream, immediately mark() and then run your detection code (but make sure it does not read ahead further than the buffer size, you can specify the buffer size in the BufferedInputStream constrcutor). Then call reset() and really read the stream.

EDIT: If you use ByteArrayInputStream anyway, that one supports mark/reset over its entire length (naturally).